# Google App Engine ManagedSSL Not Working

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, ssl

I'm using Google App Engine to host my web application [Here's the app.yaml config I'm using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/poRqO.png), using a domain that I bought through GoDaddy to set the custom domain. I've successfully set the custom domain, and the console shows that the ManagedSSL is working, when I visit the site it's still not working [The console showing the ssl for the custom domain is working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQHgw.png). The appspot.projectid.com site does have the https working but the custom domain does not.

I've followed the tutorials provided by Google Cloud, and others on medium but this issue persists. Do I need to set something on the DNS to allow the ManagedSSL to work?

Comment: It appears that the https works but simply isn't being enforced. GAE has deprecated automatic https enforcement for flexible environments.

Comment: In GoDaddy, use `domain forwarding` to forward all to the `https` address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you stated, acording to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48752601/how-to-enforce-https-traffic-to-google-app-engine-with-custom-domain#48755788), `secure: always` still works in all standard environments, but the secure option has been **deprecated** in all *flexible environments*, [see documentation here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/upgrading#appyaml_changes) or [here for Node.js](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/upgrading#appyaml_changes).

If you need this feature in your current environment, the suggested solutions require changes to your application code. Either use the custom HTTP header `X-Forwarded-Proto` to redirect the HTTP traffic to HTTPS, or use the [HTTP Strict Transport Security response header](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security_Cheat_Sheet).

Comment: Alright thank you, is it also possible to use domain forwarding to achieve this?

Comment: This actually depends on your domain service. I believe GoDaddy offers that, but I'm not sure as I don't use it myself. By doing a quick search I found this [post](https://es.godaddy.com/help/redirigir-http-a-https-automaticamente-8828?lang=en) that may help you